# .NET application fails to run in wine with erorr: "inputlanguage is not recognized by the system." Parameter name: value

Tags: .net, wine

I have a .NET app which dose not work properly with wine. At startup it shows a MessageBox with error:

> "inputlanguage is not recognized by the system." Parameter name: value

wine console log:

```
0024:fixme:keyboard:ActivateKeyboardLayout HKL_NEXT and HKL_PREV not supported
```

Based on this log I assume that my app wants to use two unimplemented functions

```
HKL_NEXT and HKL_PREV
```

I have configured wine with this prefix

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.myapp WINEARCH=win32 winetricks -q dotnet40
```

I also had no luck with .NET 4.5 and win64.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Is this .NET application developed by you or are you just running an application? If it's developed by you, please provide minimal source code to reproduce this issue.

Comment: make sure you are using the latest Wine

Comment: @riQQ Not by me.

Comment: @JoelFan wine-6.16

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/BardMusicPlayer/BardMusicPlayer/issues/82? Seems to be something that is missing / bugged in wine.

Comment: @riqq Thanks, as i guessed it is not implemented